# Expressing as a probability density function

Tags: probability, variance, density-function, function

The measuring error x is a normal random variable. Variance of the error = 4. If distribution of x can be shown by a probability density function f(x), how would you find the analytical expression of f(x)?

Comment: Do I miss something or is this question ill-posed? You say "x is a normal random variable", so it's distribution is normal. Given the variance=4, so $\sigma = 2$, that's a $\mathcal{N}(\mu,2)$ distribution with unknown $\mu$. Which has a maximum of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\approx 0.199471$ at $\mu$.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the error is assumed to be zero mean.  Thus it has a N(0,4) distribution with density $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}2}e^{-x^2/8}$. The mode is at the mean of 0, with $f(0)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}2}$.